# spring-boot auto change port if port is already used

Tags: spring-boot

I am using Windows command to run my spring-boot application with emblemed tomcat. Beside, I need to run many console application using CommandlineRunner. Off cource I am facing port in use issue.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.
Action:
Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

I can set port in every console application but I need to run at least 10 console application at the same time.

Do I have any config or solution for application auto-change port?

Answer (score 2):

You can auto generate port number to get rid from `Port was already in use`. just put `server.port= 0` in properties or yml. It is auto generate server port in `console`.

**application.properties**

```
server.port= 0
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port : 0
```

**console**

[image]

Comment: It works well thanks! Can I also control the port install of auto-generated? Like 8080 in used -> 8081(something like that...)

Comment: No because port is coming from `TCP/IP` module

Comment: It is auto handle by your `IDE`

Comment: So it is auto-handled by JRE properties when I run it as ``java -jar``?

Comment: Define server port in `Spring Boot` web and handled by `Ide(Eclipse, Netbeans, intellij)` not by `Java Runtime Environment`