# Spring Boot in Intellij won't load image

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I'm just starting to learn Spring reading "Spring In Action" and I cannot get my image to load on anything other than port 8080 (where tomcat launches).  This would be fine normally, but I have to keep restarting the program to load any changes to my webpage.

Intellij tries to run my web program on port 63342, but no images load, only text.  I believe this is an issue with Thymeleaf. I tried pointing tomcat to port 63342 but it won't load (port is in use?)

I would like it to where I can get the reload on save feature to work, and especially being able to use the shortcuts in intellij to launch the web page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this answer help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70029955/spring-boot-auto-change-port-if-port-is-already-used/70031023#70031023

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is, as I understand, that you're trying to open your `.html` template directly from IDEA. Which means you're not using the `thymeleaf engine` to render it - you're just opening the **template** itself and not the **resulting page**. If you open the source code of this page using your browser's dev tools, you will see that all your expressions stay unprocessed which leads to it trying to fetch the resources on the wrong port (e.g. `63342` instead of `8080` where your application is really running and is ready to serve the resources).

Thus, you cannot edit your templates like this. But Thymeleaf does have an option to do that. If you're running your `Spring Boot application` from the IDE directly (e.g. a profile in Intellij IDEA Ultimate) you can add the following to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

This will tell your Spring template resolver that you do not want to cache your `.html` templates and it will load the files from disk every time, so if you modify your template and then hit IDE's `build` button it should re-package your template and when you refresh your page in browser it will load (and process!) the edited one.

**Caution!** Only use this for development builds, set value to `true` for production environments to prevent unnecessary re-reading.

See [Spring Boot Docs on Hot Swapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

if you want intelj to display your image you have to add a regular **`src`** and add a **`th:src`** to show the image when the program is run. Try adding both

```
<img th:src="@{/assets/img/image.svg}" src="../static/assets/img/image.svg"/>
```